# Why does the expression 'a++ += b' give an error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

```
#include <iostream.h>
int main()
{
  int a = 2;
  int b = 3;
  a++ += b;
  std::cout << a;
}
```

My understanding of this had been that this expression would first evaluate a+b, store that value in a and then increment it. What is happening here?

Comment: What error? what `a`? what `b`?

Comment: Please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: depending on what type `a` and `b` are this expression can literally do anything. The answer assumes they are built in number types, but you should really include a [mcve]

Comment: If you want to do what you wrote in your question, then you should probably write it as `a+=b; a++;` instead of mangling it together into an error-prone construct.

Comment: Compile fine [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88b94084bcc56222) :-)

Comment: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment...
a++ itself an operation, the left side (lvalue) required a variable where processed data can be stored.

Comment: This is **not** a duplicate of any undefined behaviour. This code is not allowed to compile in standard C++. Reopened.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: If you mean `a = a + b + 1`; why not write it?

Comment: So much wrong with that code snippet.  `<iostream.h>` should be `<iostream>`, `main_program` should be `int main()`, `const int a` means you cannot do `a++`, `cout` should be `std::cout` or have a prior `using std::cout`.

Comment: @TimRandall You changed the semantics of the program by swapping `a` and `b`. `a` is even a const and should not  be incrementable at all now. Rather than swapping a and b fix the entrypoint `main_program` -> `int main()` I reverted your change

Comment: @Eljay see above comment about const a

Answer (score 9):

This is an error<sup>1</sup>:

```
a++ += b
```

because `a++` returns a temporary (a [pr-value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#prvalue)) the language forbids you to modify since it is discarded as soon as the full expression has been evaluated. This is a kind of fail safe.

---

> My understanding of this had been that this expression would first evaluate a+b, store that value in a and then increment it.

No it doesn't. According to [operator precedences](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `++` evaluates before `+=`.

---

<sup>1)</sup> This answer assumes `a` and `b` are builtin types or well-behaved user-defined class types.

Comment: This is kind of true.  For built in types this is correct.  For user types it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sometimes I prefer a simple half-truth to a complex full one.

Comment: Given the minimal information provided by OP, I think it's fair to assume that `a` and `b` are `int` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

For build in types this is a compile-time-error, as asignment needs an lvalue and a++ (which is due to operator precedence evaluated first) is an rvalue. In your example the compiler will issue an error like this [see compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/38JbV8):

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:6:9: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

6 |  a++ += b;

  |         ^

Compiler returned: 1
```

If you have a custom type (in this case nonsense, but for demonstration) which looks like this

```
class A
{
    public:

    A operator++(int)
    {
        return A{};
    }

    A operator+=(const A&)
    {
        return A{};
    }

    int i;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    A b;
    a++ += b;

    return 0;
}
```

It compiles without problems as a++ now yields a lvalue.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from wrong entry point and header there are two problems with this code.

`a` is defined as `const` so it cannot be a lvalue, so cannot be affected by ++ or += operator.Or any assignment. It's a constant!

Increment operator++ doesn't return a lvalue as well so its result cannot be an argument of assignment operators.

Comment: In the OPs question it originally read b++ ... So you should not point that out

Comment: There's been some bad editing on the Q. I've fixed it along with Pi's answer so everything matches the question's title.